# regex: strip image sizes from URL

Tags: regex, image-size

I have this image URL's with the typical image sizes in them and need to strip those out to get the *clean* image URL

I think I got something:
https://www.regex101.com/r/qS5aR8/2

Just wanted to ask if there is anything to improve and learn from?

```
var test_arr = [
    "http://url.com/0304-parapente-lagoon-Reunion-96x64.jpg", 
    "http://url.com/0304-parapente-lagoon-Reunion-960x640.jpg", 
    "http://url.com/0304-parapente-lagoon-Reunion-1500x1000.jpg", 
    "http://url.com/0304-parapente-lagoon-Reunion-1280x840-960x640.jpg", 
    "http://url.com/0304-parapente-lagoon-Reunion.jpg", 
    "http://url.com/520963918_960x540.jpg"
]
for (i = 0; i < test_arr.length; i++) { 
    console.log( test_arr[i].replace(/(-?_?[0-9]+x[0-9])\w+/g, "") );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use this,

```
.replace(/(?:[-_]?[0-9]+x[0-9]+)+/g, "")
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/qS5aR8/4)

Comment: With the `g` flag the final `+` isn’t even necessary.

Comment: `(?:[-_]?[0-9]+x[0-9]+)+(?=\.\w+$)` or `(?:[-_]?[0-9]+x[0-9]+)+(?=\.jpg$)`, https://www.regex101.com/r/qS5aR8/5 . here `m` modifier is necessary.

Comment: @Xufox don't know wheteher op want to remove all the formats looks like above.

Comment: if you want to remove the above format only if it's ebds with `.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I'd make it more robust by looking for between 2 and 4 digits:

```
[_-]?\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}
```

`\d` is 3 letters less than `[0-9]` too. :)

Comment: good call, so that becomes: `/(?:[-_]?\d{2,4}x\d{2,4})+(?=\.jpg$)/gm`

Comment: Yes, the `?:` can be removed too.